# 3D matrix visualization, like in Python

Tags: matrices, arrays, python

I want to create something like the following, however I can’t add red brackets and the commas.

[image]

This is my code:

```
\[ \left[\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]\right]
\]

\[ \left[\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]\right]
\]

\[ \left[\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right] \right]
\]
```

Answer (score 5):

Nested `matrix` produced this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\colorlet{tmp}{.}\color{red}\left[\color{tmp}
\begin{matrix}
\left[
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\right]\,& \color{red}\raisebox{-1.5em}{\scalebox{2}{,}}\\
\\
%
\left[
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\right]&
\end{matrix}
\vphantom{\begin{array}{c}~\\[8.5em]\end{array}}
\color{red}\right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could mention how to color (using `xcolor`) the outer braces appropriately, as easy grouping or `\textcolor` doesn't work with `\leftX\rightX`. I'd recommend to save the color, change to red, and change back: `\colorlet{tmp}{.}\color{red}\left[\color{tmp}`.

Comment: @nox I didn't think that OP wanted the color. Will make that change.